# Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager::createDriver() lumen and JWT

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, jwt, lumen

I am trying to implement JWT token in my API using `Lumen + JWT`. I am using this [JWT Library](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth), I have set up it, but when I want to validate passed using `JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)` I get next error

```
ErrorException in AuthManager.php line 16:
Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager::createDriver(), called in /home/admin/web/mkopilka.ru/public_html/api/referral/vendor/illuminate/support/Manager.php on line 87 and defined
```

I know where is the problem, but cannot figure out how to solve it because I don't know internals of framework well.

I have question about how does JWT authenticate the user (checks credentials in database, as I can gues it uses model class provided in `jwt.php` with the following line `'user' => 'App\Models\User'`

By default `'user' => 'App\User'`

So even if I changed user model  in this file I got the next error

```
vendor/illuminate/auth/EloquentUserProvider.php line 126:
Class '\App\User' not found
```

I thought and decided to add config/auth.php file with succeeding content

```
return [
    'model' => 'App\Models\User'
 ];
```

And now I get the the first exception.

What is wrong I can quess that I have overridden all parameters in auth config file.

Aslo I wonder where can I find (except source code, it will take a lot of time to understand it) explanation how `JWTAuth::attempt` works ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just had same issue myself and stumbled upon this question.

Solution is to add `'driver' => 'eloquent'` into your created **auth.php** file.

Comment: THIS.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on my upgrade from Laravel 4.1 to 4.2 (I think mainly because I updated all the files and tried to make a composer update *afterwards*).

For me the following worked (like reverting the relevant update steps):

## 1. Modify auth.php

Add driver, model and table to config/auth.php main array (*additionally* to the already existing one in the providers sub array):

```
<?php

return [

    'driver' => 'eloquent',
    'model' => App\User::class,
    'table' => 'users',

    // ...
```

## 2. Add ArtisanServiceProvider

To prevent the error **Artisan: Command clear-compiled is not defined** readd `Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ArtisanServiceProvider` to the service providers

```
<?php

return [

    // ...

    'providers' => [

        /*
         * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
         */
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ArtisanServiceProvider::class,

        // ...
```

## 3. Update and revert changes

Perform update (`composer update`) and revert the two previous steps by removing the added lines.